# Filling in vertical space with random height DLs

Tags: html, css

I'm setting up a menu that consists of `DL` blocks, each block holding certain options.

These `DL`s are all of varying height, though they all maintain the same width so I can fit them two at a time. These `DL`s are contained within a `div` area.

What I'm trying to do is make it that when one block is visibly longer than another block, the next block in line will squeeze to the one side and come up just below the block below it.

```
<div id="contentarea">
    <dl>This Dl has one DT and two DDs in it, one per line.</dl>
    <dl>This DL has one DT and six DDs in it, one per line.</dl>
    <dl>This DL has one DT and four DDs in it, one per line.</dl>
</div>
```

The idea is that since the second `DL` takes more vertical space, the third `DL` would automatically push itself to the right and take up the space underneath the first `DL`. If this third `D`L would make the left side longer than the right, then the next `DL` would go right. If it's the same or still less, then it goes to the left again until it exceeds the right.

I will note, I'm trying to NOT define the `DL`s as having different classes.

In my CSS, I have my `DL`s defined to `display` as `inline-block`, as just `inline` caused them to not actually use the right side properly and just show each `d`l below the one before it.

As `inline-block`, though, all they do is just make individual rows without filling in space between some `DL`s. With `inline-block`, they now use the right side as well, but when a third one comes in, it drops to below the longest point instead of trying to fill in the next immediate spot like I want it to.

Comment: I dont know much but if you define a width to dl dont works?

Comment: I do have defined widths. Each DL is defined as having 48% of the total area. However, when it gets to the third DL, it makes an entire new row instead of butting itself up.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using DLs?

It sounds like the effect you want can be achieved using masonry.js

http://masonry.desandro.com/

take a look.

Comment: I'm using DLs to separate menu items. Each DL is a new menu, with the DT being the heading of that menu and each DD being what's under that menu.

Hmm... that does look like it'd work, but I'm kinda hoping I can work it without Javascript. I'm gonna keep an eye out for any other solution, since I don't see why it wouldn't be possible.